# All video players display black screen

Tags: 10.04, video, nvidia

I'm working in 10.04 Lucid. All my video players (Movie Player and VLC) and the preview windows in editors (OpenShot and Pitivi) will only display a black screen when playing a video. The sound is fine and the videos work fine on other computers.

I have tried multiple formats from varying sources .MOV taken from old ffmpeg projects,  .AVI straight from a camera, .MP4 using h.264 from OpenShot on another system, .OGV from a gtk-recordmydesktop session on this very computer. I even get a pure black screen in the viewer when starting a remote session in VNC.

This box has a GeForce 8400 GS using the proprietary Nvidia drivers in case it may be a card problem or setting.

Comment: Are you using the proprietary Nvidia drivers or the Xorg Nvidia drivers?   Also, have you tried disabling Compiz or other eye-candy?

Comment: Nvidia. Yes to no effect.

Comment: I'm at a loss.  The best suggestions I have is try re-installing the drivers or trying the non-proprietary nv driver.  If the problem is still there with the nv driver, then it is most likely not a driver issue.  Good Luck.

Comment: Removing and reinstalling the Nvidia drivers did the trick, why don't you post an answer and I'll accept it. Linking to a post of the process would be a plus for future folks finding this.

Comment: ...because it was a complete long-shot :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm at a loss. The best suggestions I have is try re-installing the drivers or trying the non-proprietary nv driver. If the problem is still there with the nv driver, then it is most likely not a driver issue.

Good Luck

Comment: There is not doubt a nice fast command line way to do this. However wanting to try it quick without a lot of research I went to System > Administration > Hardware Drivers found the Nvidia driver and clicked remove which required a restart. Then tested it and all video was fine. Next I went to System > Preferences > Appearance and tried to restore  some of the effects which prompted me to re-install the proprietary drivers. I did, re-started, turned all effects back on, and the video still worked. Don't know if it is a universal fix, but in "one man's experience..."

Comment: Did not work for me unfortunately...

Answer (score 2):

I found this worked.

1. Open the Configuration Editor by running

   ```
   gconf-editor
   ```

   in the terminal.
2. Navigate to **system → gstreamer → 0.10 → default**
3. Double-click on **videosink** and change the setting from **autovideosink** to **ximagesink**